# parse values based on groups in R

Tags: r, grouping, gsub, substitution

I have a very large dataset and a sample of that looks something like the one below:

```
| Id | Name    | Start_Date | End_Date   |
|----|---------|------------|------------|
| 10 | Mark    | 4/2/1999   | 7/5/2018   |
| 10 |         | 1/1/2000   | 9/24/2018  |
| 25 |         | 5/3/1968   | 6/3/2000   |
| 25 |         | 6/6/2009   | 4/23/2010  |
| 25 | Anthony | 2/20/2010  | 7/21/2016  |
| 25 |         | 9/12/2014  | 11/26/2019 |
```

I need to parse the names from `Name` column based on their `Id` such that the output table looks like:

```
| Id | Name    | Start_Date | End_Date   |
|----|---------|------------|------------|
| 10 | Mark    | 4/2/1999   | 7/5/2018   |
| 10 | Mark    | 1/1/2000   | 9/24/2018  |
| 25 | Anthony | 5/3/1968   | 6/3/2000   |
| 25 | Antony  | 6/6/2009   | 4/23/2010  |
| 25 | Anthony | 2/20/2010  | 7/21/2016  |
| 25 | Anthony | 9/12/2014  | 11/26/2019 |
```

How can I achieve an output as shown above? I went through the substitute and parse functions, but was unable to understand how they apply to this problem.

My dataset would be:

```
df=data.frame(Id=c("10","10","25","25","25","25"),Name=c("Mark","","","","Anthony",""),
              Start_Date=c("4/2/1999", "1/1/2000","5/3/1968","6/6/2009","2/20/2010","9/12/2014"),
              End_Date=c("7/5/2018","9/24/2018","6/3/2000","4/23/2010","7/21/2016","11/26/2019"))
```

Comment: @AlexW I have corrected the mistake

Comment: @akrun I checked trying both the codes. The first one gives an error : 'arg' should be one of “down”, “up” and the second one doesn't fill out the blank records.

Comment: I am using the `devel` version of `tidyr`.  which may have the `.direction = 'downup'`  if you are usisng regular one, `%>% fill(Name) %>% fill(Name, .direction = "up")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can change the blanks (`""`) to `NA` and use `fill` to replace the NA elements with the previous non-NA element

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%      
   mutate(Name = na_if(Name, "")) %>%
   group_by(Id) %>%
   fill(Name, .direction = "down") %>%
   fill(Name, .direction = "up)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   Id [2]
#  Id    Name    Start_Date End_Date  
#  <chr> <chr>   <chr>      <chr>     
#1 10    Mark    4/2/1999   7/5/2018  
#2 10    Mark    1/1/2000   9/24/2018 
#3 25    Anthony 5/3/1968   6/3/2000  
#4 25    Anthony 6/6/2009   4/23/2010 
#5 25    Anthony 2/20/2010  7/21/2016 
#6 25    Anthony 9/12/2014  11/26/2019
```

In the `devel` version of `tidyr` (`‘0.8.3.9000’`), this can be done in a single `fill` statement as `.direction = "downup"` is also an option

```
df1 %>%      
   mutate(Name = na_if(Name, "")) %>%
   group_by(Id) %>%
   fill(Name, .direction = "downup")
```

---

Or another option is to group by 'Id', and `mutate` the 'Name' as the `first` non-blank element

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(Id) %>%        
    mutate(Name = first(Name[Name!=""])) 
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   Id [2]
#  Id    Name    Start_Date End_Date  
#  <chr> <chr>   <chr>      <chr>     
#1 10    Mark    4/2/1999   7/5/2018  
#2 10    Mark    1/1/2000   9/24/2018 
#3 25    Anthony 5/3/1968   6/3/2000  
#4 25    Anthony 6/6/2009   4/23/2010 
#5 25    Anthony 2/20/2010  7/21/2016 
#6 25    Anthony 9/12/2014  11/26/2019
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Id = c("10", "10", "25", "25", "25", "25"), Name = c("Mark", 
"", "", "", "Anthony", ""), Start_Date = c("4/2/1999", "1/1/2000", 
"5/3/1968", "6/6/2009", "2/20/2010", "9/12/2014"), End_Date = c("7/5/2018", 
"9/24/2018", "6/3/2000", "4/23/2010", "7/21/2016", "11/26/2019"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: The above code is filling up blanks with wrong names. I want the blanks to be filled with the names based on id. For example, id="10" has "Name=Mark", so it should fill all the blank records in Name column with Mark. So that would be only 2 records for Mark. Could you please look in to it?

Comment: @hk2  I think you need to just add `Id` in the group.  Updatdd the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked with both "up" and "down" as direction.

Answer (score 3):

Using `DF` defined reproducibly in the Note at the end, replace each zero-length element of `Name` with NA and then use `na.omit` to get the unique non-NA to use to fill.  We have assumed that there is only one non-NA per `Id` which is the case in the question.   If not we could replace `na.omit` with `function(x) unique(na.omit(x))` assuming that the non-NAs are all the same within `Id`. No packages are used.

```
transform(DF, Name = ave(replace(Name, !nzchar(Name), NA), Id, FUN = na.omit))
```

giving:

```
  Id    Name Start_Date   End_Date
1 10    Mark   4/2/1999   7/5/2018
2 10    Mark   1/1/2000  9/24/2018
3 25 Anthony   5/3/1968   6/3/2000
4 25 Anthony   6/6/2009  4/23/2010
5 25 Anthony  2/20/2010  7/21/2016
6 25 Anthony  9/12/2014 11/26/2019
```

### na.strings

We can simplify this slightly if we make sure that the zero length elements of `Name` are NA in the first place.  We replace the `read.table` line in the Note with the first line below.  Then it is just a matter of using `na.locf0`.

```
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, sep = "|", 
  strip.white = TRUE, na.strings = "")

transform(DF, Name = ave(Name, Id, FUN = na.omit))
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "
 Id | Name    | Start_Date | End_Date   
 10 | Mark    | 4/2/1999   | 7/5/2018   
 10 |         | 1/1/2000   | 9/24/2018  
 25 |         | 5/3/1968   | 6/3/2000   
 25 |         | 6/6/2009   | 4/23/2010  
 25 | Anthony | 2/20/2010  | 7/21/2016  
 25 |         | 9/12/2014  | 11/26/2019"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE)
```

Comment: This does not produce the output as desired. The names should be filled based on their id's. So, Mark should only fill twice and Anthony should be filled 4 times. Could you please refer to sample output to see how this can be achieved? Thanks in advance!