# Is there a way to pull from the last non-blank value in a column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table with a list of actions:

```
   name         person         timestamp           open_count               
 Opened            A      2019-07-01 00:00:34      1
 Action            A      2019-07-01 00:00:34      
 Action            A      2019-07-01 00:00:34      
 Opened            A      2019-07-02 00:00:34      2
 Action            A      2019-07-01 00:00:34      
 Action            A      2019-07-01 00:00:34      
 Opened            A      2019-07-08 00:00:34      3
 Action            A      2019-07-01 00:00:34      
 Action            A      2019-07-01 00:00:34      
 Action            A      2019-07-01 00:00:34      
 Opened            A      2019-07-11 00:00:34      4
```

I'd like to fill in the value for `open_count` to the last non-null value in the column. My goal is to create a session so that I can look at the number of actions for each time a user took the open action.

How do I fill in the last non-null value? You can imagine the timestamps are in ascending order.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57677225/parse-values-based-on-groups-in-r

Comment: Are you just trying to fill the `open_count` column downwards?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the blank is `""`

```
df1[tail(which(colSums(df1 != "") == nrow(df1)), 1)]
```

or if it is `NA`

```
df1[tail(which(colSums(!is.na(df1)) == nrow(df1)), 1)]
```

---

If we need to `fill` the 'open_count'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(open_count = na_if(open_count, "")) %>% 
   fill(open_count)
```

Comment: How would you do this if you wanted to group it by each user?

Comment: @Cauder  I added a group by, but not cleaer about the expecteed

Comment: That's not correct. It gives my four columns with the value TRUE.

Comment: @Cauder which one, the group_by?.  Can you update your post with the expected

Comment: This worked for me df1 %>%
    group_by(grp = cumsum(!is.na(Name))) %>%
    mutate(Name = first(Name)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp), except open_coutn instead of name

Comment: @Cauder In your eexamplee, there is no blank for Name

Comment: @Cauder Try `df1 %>% mutate(open_coutn = na_if(open_coutn, "")) %>% fill(open_coutn)`